# set Model in Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How `Set Model` in `Spinner` in android like following array we can set.

```
this.mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Planets,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

But instead of `R.array.Planets` we want to set some Model or been it have id, country. 
so i can get id of selected country right now spinner provide me selected index.

Answer (score 0):

You did not bother telling us what "some Model" is.

If "some Model" is a `Cursor`, use a `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

If "some Model" is something else, create your own subclass of `BaseAdapter` that will work with "some Model".